# How much oxygen will we need to combust 100 grams of diamond

Tags: organic-chemistry

How much oxygen will we need to fully combust 100 grams of diamond given in weight and volume at standard pressure and temperature

Answer (score 1):

diamond is pure C, so just take the mass, look up how many atoms ("mole") per mass.
Realize that the result of combustion is CO2, meaning 2 oxygen atoms per atom C, look up the mass per mole of oxygen, et voilá.

Then look up what gases at one atmosphere pressure take up in terms of volume and you have that, also.

Comment: With your answer, OP can stop thinking and just follow the recipe instead. Not good.

Comment: @Karl There's so many fully calculated answers to such homework dumps then this relatively good, and, from new user, surprisingly good.

Comment: @Mithoron Agreed. I still doubt OP is going to learn anything. Well, you can't force people, can you? ;-)